# Vuforia initialization failed

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, vuforia

Im having a Unity project that I wantto run on Android. So far I have just a simple example with Vuforia library integration. It works as expected on my android device.
Problems start when I want to add Firebase support. So I downloaded the Firebase packages for Unity, and install the database package in order to have database sync support. So far so good.

From that moment, my Vuforia enabled scene won't work anymore on the android device :

- from adb : `Vuforia cannot be started before it is initialized. Please disable Delayed Initializationin the Vuforia configuration or initialize Vuforia manually with the VuforiaRuntime-class.`
- that option is already disabled.

[Edit] I managed to solve the issues described below. This was only a permission issue, Unity wasn't allowed to write in the Android SDK directory...

<del>While Vuforia is no longer working, Unity starts to show some "Install Android Packages" over and over again. Every time I build, or even every time I click play within the editor... I'm assuming it's because the installation fails, I have a few error messages in the Unity console :</del>

- <del>`Unable to find dependency com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.0.0 in paths ($SDK\extras\android\m2repository, $SDK\extras\google\m2repository).`</del>
- <del>`Unable to find dependency com.google.firebase:firebase-common:11.0.0 in paths ($SDK\extras\android\m2repository, $SDK\extras\google\m2repository).`</del>
- <del>`Unable to find dependency com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.0 in paths ($SDK\extras\android\m2repository, $SDK\extras\google\m2repository).`</del>
- <del>`Unable to find dependency com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.0 in paths ($SDK\extras\android\m2repository, $SDK\extras\google\m2repository).`</del>

Any one has encountered these problems ?

My Software :

- Windows 8.1
- Android 6.0.2
- Firebase SDK 4.0.0
- Unity 5.5.0f3
- Vuforia SDK Unity 6.2.10